# Devise No method error issue in rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I just created rails 3.1 app and updated devise 1.4.7.But  When i browse http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up(as indicated in rake routes) ,I get " NoMethodError in Devise/registrations#new " extracted source is line

```
  3: <%= form_for(resource_name, resource, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do  |f| %>.
```

What is the solution to this?Thank you in advance.

routes.rb

```
    Deals::Application.routes.draw do
    devise_for :users
    match  "/users/sign_up" => "devise/registrations#new"

    root :to => "home#index"
      end
```

Answer (score 2):

Use these lines in your routes.rb file.

```
root :to => "home#index"
devise_for :users
devise_scope :user do
    get "sign_in", :to => "devise/sessions#new"
    get "sign_out", :to => "devise/sessions#destroy"
    get "sign_up", :to => "devise/registrations#new"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Restarting the server did it for me. Try it before anything else!

Answer (score 0):

Take out this part in `config/routes.rb`:

`match  "/users/sign_up" => "devise/registrations#new"`

That's redundant, `devise_for :users` will add that route.

Comment: when i take that one out i get Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_up"

Comment: Something is configured wrong I think. Maybe you're using a custom scope? Can you post your routes.rb and the output of rake routes?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `devise_for :users` followed directly by `resources :users`